# Git: Merging to a branch from another branch using Kdiff3

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging, kdiff3

I'm familiar with ClearCase where we can merge a file to a branch from any other branch. How is this possible in git?
For eg, I have the following structure

```
master--->branch_2
  |
  |
  V
branch_1
```

So there is some independent development going in `branch_1` and `branch_2`. I want to merge some specific code from `branch_2` to `branch_1` using some mergetool like kdiff3.

EDIT:
Kdiff3 has an awesome merging option by comparing 2 or 3 versions of the file (from same or different branch), highlighting the conflicts. Then we can jump through each conflict, and pick the code from 1 or more versions of the file, make some edits (if necessary) and finally save the file. This feature has been quite handy for me when I worked with ClearCase. Is there a way to configure git mergetool with kdiff3 to work the same way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "_some specific code_"? Do you want to merge some specific _commits_, some _files_ from specific commits or just some _changes_ from specific files in specific commits? You can do any of them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to merge a specific *portion* of changes from a given commit in `branch_2`.

If that's the case, you can use `git cherry-pick --no-commit` or (`-n`) to apply the changes from a commit in `branch_2` *without creating a new commit*. From that point you can decide which changes to commit by staging only portions of the modified files.

Here's an example:

```
git checkout branch_1
git cherry-pick -n <some-commit>  # 1. Apply the changes from some commit in branch_2
                                  # without creating a new commit
git reset HEAD                    # 2. Unstage all changes from that commit
git add -p                        # 3. Decide which changes to include in the commit
git commit                        # 4. Commit those changes
```

Answer (score 1):

Standing in branch_1 you can simple `cherry-pick` whatever commit you want from branch_2.

```
git cherry-pick <some sha1>
```

You can also rebase your work in branch_1 so it comes after branch_2

```
git rebase --onto branch_2 branch_1
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to integrate the git cherry-pick with the merge functionality of kdiff3?

Comment: I believe that if you get a conflict from cherry-picking you'll just have to launch kdiff3 to resolve the conflict, just as with any conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Be on target branch:

```
git checkout branch1
```

Edit the branch1 code while refering to branch2 version

```
git difftool branch2 -- file.txt
```

Commit changes as usual

```
git add file.txt
git commit
```

Comment: But the difftool command just gives me a diff for a file between the two branches. It doesn't provide a merging option...

Comment: `git diff` just gives a diff. `git difftool` invokes the currently configured difftool. If it is a difftool that has an edit or merge capability (such as vimdiff - maybe even kdiff3, I never used it), you will be able to merge (as in edit-merge, not `git merge`). If you have specific commits you wish to transport to another branch, as opposed to actually using a merging tool to pick what you wish, then use the suggestion by Andreas.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. By "diff", I actually meant "difference"; not the 'git diff'. Anyway now I get what you mean. I use kdiff3 and I can't edit when it is showing the differences (at least not that I am aware of). I can make changes only by invoking it from the 'git mergetool' command. Thanks anyway!!